# Is that I have no way to use Selenium in Bloomberg.com?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to retrieve some financial data in Bloomberg, however I found that it can realise that the execution is a bot/automation or something.

```
import  ws_functions.config                 as ws_config
import  ws_functions.cust_functions         as ws_functions
import  time
import  sqlite3
from    selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


ws_functions.print_runtime()

bloomberg_frontpage_url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/asia'
browser                 = ws_functions.get_ChromeDriver((""))
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

try:
    browser.get(bloomberg_frontpage_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-bar-search-button"]').click() #Click "Search"
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navi-search-input"]').send_keys('HSI') #Send 'HSI' to the searchbar
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('HSI:IND').click()
```

May I know how I can resolve this?
The upon is my all codes so far, hope someone can advise me, thanks all :)

Below is the website popped to me:
[image]

I would like to scrape the below data:
[image]

Here is the direct URL to the Hang Seng Index :
https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/HSI:IND

Comment: I found that there are 2nd questions that why the webpage is keep loading?
My code is waiting the loading until finish....

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got a workaround to just simply call the Bloomberg API to retrieve that instead of using the mentioning solution, thanks.